# react-native text doesn't align

Tags: css, react-native

My text component doesn't align when the text is more than 2 lines (see screenshot). I have tried playing around with alignment and ellipsizeMode but none of the settings change anything. Why is the 2nd line indented?

[image: 2nd line is misaligned]

My code:

```
<View style={{ flex: 4, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10}}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
    <CircleIndicator style={{marginRight: 29}} />
    <View
      style={{
        width: 4,
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: styles.colors.lipstick,
        marginRight: 35,
      }}
    />
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text weight='bold' color='darkIndigo'> {activityType} </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text color='blueyGrey' style={{opacity: 0.5}}> {activityDate}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 30 }}>
      <Text color='blueyGrey'> {activityDescription} </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
    <Text weight='bold' color='lipstick'> {activityPoints} PTS </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: first and second line is o/p of which var?

Comment: it's the activityDescription

Comment: what about  `textAlign: 'flex-start'`

Comment: Gives the same result :(

Comment: In a flex row direction you need `justifyContent: 'center'`

Comment: What about  textAlign:'center'

Comment: neither ways make a difference :(

Comment: @stoerebink try changing flexdirection row to column and see the result. You have all the elements in one row

Comment: My page consists of 3 columns, with a variable amount of rows, that's why it's flexDirection column. Wrapping activity description in a view with flexdirection column doesnt help either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I left this issue alone for a couple of days and revisited it. The reason for the misalignment was this:

```
<Text color='blueyGrey'> {activityDescription} </Text>
```

Changed it to:

```
<Text color='blueyGrey'>{activityDescription}</Text>
```

Such a rookie mistake :D

Comment: I've came across this same problem years after your post. Your mistake more than likely saved many people(including myself) hours of frustration! Thanks!